# UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout decorationItems excluding header and footer

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

The new `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` introduced in iOS 13 have a property named `decorationItems` for adding decoration items conveniently, which you could use to add a background for the section.

```
let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
section.decorationItems = [
   NSCollectionLayoutDecorationItem.background(elementKind:"your identifier")
]
```

Which is working fine for the full section.

> what I want is to add a decoration view only on items since I want
> rounded background only for section items excluding header and footer.
> could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a property `contentInsets` on `NSCollectionLayoutDecorationItem` in order to exclude header and footer

Comment: this didn’t work unfortunately plus my header has dynamic height